# Overloading operator in different ways depending on template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```
template<int n> MyClass<n>
```

for which I am trying to define the `operator &`. I want to be able to perform MyClass&MyClass, but also MyClass&MyClass<1> (or MyClass<1>&MyClass would work for me as well) with a different functionality obviously.

```
template <size_t n>
struct MyClass
{
    //...a lot of stuff
    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<n> &other) const;

    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<1> &other) const;
}
```

However, I am not able to compile this, as for the case of n being 1 they collide. I tried adding SFINAE, but apparently I don't understand it well enough to use it in this case.

```
template <size_t n>
struct MyClass
{
    //...a lot of stuff
    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<n> &other) const;

    std::enable_if_t<n != 1, MyClass<n>> operator&(const MyClass<1> &other) const;
}
```

Does not work for making sure the case of n being 1 doesn't cause issues. I think it is because SFINAE works for the function template parameters itself, but not the class template parameters.

I believe I could to a specialization of `MyClass<1>`, but then I would have to replicate all the contents of `MyClass<n>`. Is there any easy solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE only works with templates. You can make the 1st `operator&` template as:

```
template <size_t n>
struct MyClass
{
    //...a lot of stuff
    template <size_t x>
    std::enable_if_t<x == n, MyClass<x>> // ensure only MyClass<n> could be used as right operand 
    operator&(const MyClass<x> &other) const;

    // overloading with the template operator&
    // non-template is perferred when MyClass<1> passed
    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<1> &other) const;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aiiVm1mEC1O3mK2M)

Comment: This is really interesting! What is the reason that there is no issue with 1==x==n? You write it is because non-template is preferred, but why isn't that also the case in my first example?

Comment: @DottyPhone In your example, both `operator&` are non-template and takes `const MyClass<1> &`, they have the exact signature and you'll get a redeclaration error. In my code one is template and another is non-template; their signatures are different and then overloaded.

Comment: Ohh I see! True, in my case the n comes from the class :) I missed that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use constraint (require c++20)

```
template <size_t n>
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<n> &) const { std::cout << "1\n"; return {}; }
    MyClass<n> operator&(const MyClass<1> &) const requires (n!=1) { std::cout << "2\n"; return {}; }
};
```

Comment: Not using c++20 but it's great that they added this!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with operator overloading, don't give operators meaning beyond something that can be expected. In almost all cases it is better to create functions with readable names (for maintainability).

What you want to do can I think be done with "if constexpr", example :

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct MyClass
{
    void do_something() const
    {
        if constexpr (N == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "behavior 1\n";
        }
        else
        if constexpr (N == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "behavior 2\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<1> c1;
    MyClass<2> c2;

    c1.do_something();
    c2.do_something();

    return 0;
}
```